# Multinomial (nnet) does not work using parsnip and broom

Tags: broom, nnet, tidymodels

I'm trying to run a multinomial (nnet) using tidymodel, but it shows me the next result:

Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

```
data(iris)
ml<-multinom_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("nnet") %>% 
  set_mode("classification") %>% 
  translate()
ml_fit <- ml %>% 
  fit(Species ~ Sepal.Width, data=iris) 
broom::tidy(ml_fit, exponentiate = F)
```

But when I run ... works perfectly

```
formula <- Species ~ Sepal.Width
model <- nnet::multinom(formula, data = iris)
broom::tidy(model, exponentiate = F)
```

Any idea of whether or not I'm writing properly the tidy model or is something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tidymodels, we handle things in a way that the original data and formula are not contained in the resulting call (in the usual way). Some parts of `multinom()` want those (plus the actual data in the same place) to do the computations.

We just [changed](https://github.com/tidymodels/parsnip/pull/316) how we handle the formula; that now comes through as it would have if you called `multinom()` directly. We can't really do the same with `data` but we did add a new function called `repair_call()` that you can use to make things they way that you want them.

```
# devtools::install_dev("parsnip")
library(parsnip)
library(broom)
multi_spec <- multinom_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("nnet") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")
multi_fit <- multi_spec %>% 
  fit(Species ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris) 
tidy(multi_fit)
#> Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE): cannot coerce class '"function"' to a data.frame


multi_fit_new <- repair_call(multi_fit, iris)
tidy(multi_fit_new)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   y.level    term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>      <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 versicolor (Intercept)  1.55e+8     3.06       6.15 7.54e-10
#> 2 versicolor Sepal.Width  2.20e-3     0.991     -6.17 6.70e-10
#> 3 virginica  (Intercept)  4.41e+5     2.69       4.83 1.33e- 6
#> 4 virginica  Sepal.Width  1.69e-2     0.844     -4.84 1.33e- 6
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>